# Manipulating Oracle APEX Regions with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Application Express (APEX) where I have created a Report Region and as part of the title of that I region, I have entered the following:

```
<div id="abc" style="font-weigh:bold;font-size:18px;"></div>
```

In the region source, I have my required SQL report query.

I am attempting to use jQuery so that I can hide and show this region based on div id value of "abc". When I attempt to use `$("#abc").show();` or `$("#abc").hide()'`, nothing happens from the looks of it (it can't find this div id?).

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible when using an APEX SQL report region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you issue $("#abc").hide(), JQuery hides the contents of the div with id "abc" - i.e. any HTML/text between the opening <div> and closing </div> tags.  In your example there is nothing between these tags to hide and so nothing will change.

If you want to hide the entire region then the div needs to surround the entire region.  You could achieve this by removing the </div> tag from the title and adding it in the region footer.  However there are much easier ways to achieve this:

1) Give the region a Static ID of "abc".  Your show/hide code will then work without the need to add your own div tags.

2) If you are using Apex 4.0, create a Dynamic Action to show/hide the region instead of writing JQuery code.

Comment: Thanks Tony - I will give this a try and write back. Unfortunately I am still on 3.0.1. I was starting to think that this wasn't possible with the way I want to use it.

Comment: Hi Tony. Unfortunately this didn't seem to work on a SQL Report region when I used the Static ID. Now I'm not sure if it's b/c I am using Apex 3.0.1, or b/c it's an SQL Report region, or something else?

Comment: It depends on what the region template does with the static id.  If you are using an older theme maybe it doesn't reference it at all?  Perhaps you could copy and paste the source of the region template into your question so we can take a look?

Comment: Spot on Tony - that's it. I forgot to include the substitution string #REGION_STATIC_ID# in my region template for this SQL Report. It's been a while since I developed my own region templates but thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Your ideea works.

Go int "EDIT REGION" for the region you want to hide/show :

`<div id="abc" style="font-weigh:bold;font-size:18px;">` put it in  **Region Header** and of course `</div>` in the **Region Footer**.

The Jquery will work fine.

Test it out with firebug to see if the selector returns any result.

I have done this plenty of times and i think using Dynamic Actions only complicates things.